# Extract IP address from buffer in C++ (Linux sockets)

Tags: c++, sockets, ip

Is it possible to extract the destination and source IP addresses in the following case? I was able to extract Ethernet source and destination addresses from `in_buffer`. Any suggestion if it is possible to do it?

```
sockaddr_ll sockaddr = sockaddr_ll();

sockaddr.sll_family = PF_PACKET;
sockaddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
// is the interface index of the interface
sockaddr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(argv[1]);
sockaddr.sll_hatype = 1;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;

raw_protocol_t::socket socket(io_service, raw_protocol_t(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW));
socket.bind(raw_endpoint_t(&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)));

boost::asio::generic::raw_protocol::socket::receive_buffer_size option;
socket.get_option(option);

std::string in_buffer(option.value(), '\0');

raw_endpoint_t rep = raw_endpoint_t();

while (true)
{
   size_t len = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(&in_buffer[0], in_buffer.size()), rep);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if that's obvious from your code but are the IP addresses in binary or readable form?

Comment: well I don't know. I'm trying to extract them

Comment: If you don't know then extracting them is impossible. You have to know the format of the addresses at least. Can you print them out without any further conversion? If yes, they are strings of characters, i.e., readable.

Comment: should I use asio to extract them or some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can read IP address from the raw packet buffer. Of course only if there is an IP address in the packet. The data stored in the `in_buffer` contains complete packet including IP header if the protocol is IP.

Note the received data may contain any protocol. It can be IPv4 and then you can find IP addresses there but it can be IPv6 or even more obscure protocol without IP addresses.

Let assume the received packet is an `Ethernet-II` packet containing `IPv4` data. Then you can easily get IP addresses:

```
  // Source addr
  printf("%d.%d.%d.%d", (unsigned char)(in_buffer[26]),
                        (unsigned char)(in_buffer[27]),
                        (unsigned char)(in_buffer[28]),
                        (unsigned char)(in_buffer[29]));
  // Destination addr
  printf("%d.%d.%d.%d", (unsigned char)(in_buffer[30]),
                        (unsigned char)(in_buffer[31]),
                        (unsigned char)(in_buffer[32]),
                        (unsigned char)(in_buffer[33]));
```

Sure it is not nice and you need check if the buffer contains what is expected but it is up to you.

And what does the magic number means 26 - 32?

The Ethernet II header has size 14 bytes. First 6 bytes are destination MAC, next 6 bytes are source MAC and the last 2 bytes ethertype. Ethertype 0x0800 means the data contain IPv4. The source IPv4 address is at offset 12 in IP header and the destination IP is at offset 16. So the magic number 26 means offset from packet begin and its 14(ethernetHeaderSize) + 12(offsetInIPHeader).

Comment: and the source port and destination port?

Comment: Ports are more complicated. They are in UDP or TCP header.  You need determine the length of the IP header (usually 20 bytes but it may be longer), identify the type of payload (1 byte at offset 9 in the IP header) and if it is TCP or UDP read ports as `unsigned short`s from UDP or TCP header. See header definition in RFCs or at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol. or you can use an existing library for header processing like http://research.wand.net.nz/software/libtrace.php

Comment: @ZabojCampula I do believe there is an error in indexing of the buffer. When you re indexing the dest address you take last two octets from the same place in buffer.